# protege ontop: sparql query not return any result

Tags: sparql, protege

I'm running protege 5.5.0 with ontop4.2 on win10 64bit
based on tutorial i should have some result on sparql query,but i get a blank result . (ontop reasoner is also started before run query)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: does it work in the "Ontop SPARQL" tab?

Comment: yes it does.thanks